# document.getElementByID doesn't work when using browserify

Tags: javascript, html, dom, browserify

I have a file which finds an `select` element and then sets the function for it's `onchange`. However, this doesn't work with the file browserify outputs.

Here is a minimum reproducible sample:

- A select tag with a unique id
- The following javascript file:

```
let locationSelector = document.getElementById('location');
locationSelector.onchange = function () {
    console.log('location changed');
};
```

The above works when I use the script above. However, when I use the file browserify outputs instead I get the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'onchange')`.

Logging locationSelector before the the second line shows the locationSelector in the original file but logs null in the browserify file.

Comment: I also wanted to add I tried using type="text/javascript" and "module"

Comment: It's likely that your script is running before the page's HTML has fully loaded, so the `#location` element simply doesn't exist yet. So if you're using `src=""` then add `defer` to your `<script>` - **or** move your logic into a `DOMContentLoaded` event-listener.

Comment: yup defer worked, thanks a lot!